# Specialize non-generic type

Tags: swift, generics

In Swift 2, I had a function delared like this :

```
private func lineCharts(_ m: Double, _ numberOfMonths: Range<Int>) -> [LineChartDataSet]
```

In swift 3 I have 3 error messages :

- Use of undeclared type <#Bound: Comparable#>
- cannot specialize non-generic type 'Range'
- 'Range' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Can someone explain what's happening there ?

Comment: Can't repro. (1) Have you filled in all placeholders in the source code? (2) Do you have another custom Range type?

Comment: _"`Range` is ambiguous for type lookup in this context"_ tells us that you've most likely defined another `Range` type (or one exists via some module you import) that comes in conflict with the native type (hence the ambiguity), which in turn explains why you get the error that you cannot specialize a non-generic type (since your own custom/other module `Range` is not generic).

Comment: Hi, it seems that you are right. The framework 'Charts' define a Range Type (for double actually). So I tried to pass a CountableClosedRange<Int> instead. Unfortunately I still have the first error.

Comment: I also tried Swift.Range<Int> but still have the <#Boud: Comparable#> issue